# is this correct? where i am trying to get multiple columns from 3 tables using alias name for each column using union

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this correct? where I am trying to get multiple columns from 3 tables using Alias name for each column using union.

```
SELECT pid AS id, product AS [product], type AS [type], product_image AS [image]
FROM products
UNION
SELECT cmid AS id, combo_name AS [product], type AS [type], cimg AS [image]
FROM combos
UNION
SELECT did AS id, deal_name AS [product], type AS [type], dimg AS [image]
FROM deals
```

I am not getting results from this query.

Comment: If you are not getting results, are you getting an error?

Comment: Side note: In a union query, there is no point of using aliases to the columns that belong to any query but the first.

Comment: And if no errors, are you getting any results from any of the three queries by themselves?  or, better yet, run these and see what you get... `Select count(*) from products`;  `Select count(*) from combos`;  `Select count(*) from deals`;

Comment: Even if `UNION` were filtering off some records, if there be _any_ records returned from even one query, then the result set should not be empty.

Comment: `I am not getting results from this query.` ... Are you getting _no_ results, or just not the results you expect?

Comment: No results are shown from this query .

Comment: 1) please add the tables definition 2) where do you run the query from?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t (i image)

select * from t 
union
select * from t
```

> Msg 5335, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The data type image cannot be used
>   as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it
>   is not comparable.

```
select * from t 
union all
select * from t
```

> (0 row(s) affected)